# Edit Mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

it is just a simple question but i want to solve it as best as possible.

There will be a table in html, which would be filled with data from a mysql query,
for example:

```
name | street | zip
```

What i want is to make this changeable, so that user can directly change the results -> click on save -> Update via mysql.

My plan was now, to display the data in input fields which are named like this:

```
name_id | street_id | zip_id
```

By clicking on save i would perform a while-loop to get all names, streets, and zips of the id and perform an mysql update afterwords. I know that this would be possible that way (i already used this 1 time).

But: is there a more easier and better solution for this problem?

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use javascript this is the way to do it!
I was just working with this a few hours ago.
http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/edatagrid.php

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for :) Well Ill try this out tomorrow, but seems to be very nice :)

Comment: Best thing about it is that you have all the documentation and examples you need. Also more people are using it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Updating all elements could cause heavy load on your server, depending on the amount of data you have stored. A more performance-friendly solution would be to "save" the row keys of the data that you changed. If you do this, you would only update the rows that actually changed, and not all rows!